# Properties of a solution of a second order ODE

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f\in\mathcal{C}^{2}$ and $f$ is solution for the ODE;

$f''(x)+xf'(x)=\cos(x^3f'(x))$

**Prove or disprove :**

*a) $f$ is an odd function*

*b) $f$ has at most one critical point*

*c) The equation $f(x)=0$ has at most two solutions*

My work so far:

a) Suppose $f$ is even then we have that the sum of two even functions is an even function, which is correct, so $f$ is not necessarily odd.

b) Let $k$ be a critical point the ODE tell us that $f''(k)=1>0$ so that point is a local minimum but I cant get any further.

c) I have a guess that b) implies c) but how?

Edit: b) So if it was to reach another minimum point it should start to grow and then decrease again,but that would imply in the existence of a point where $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)<0$ is that correct?

Comment: False result $(xf'(x))'=cos(x^{3}f'(x))$.

Comment: Thank you,I'll reavaluate the parity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Your "proof" isn't correct. The fact that you didn't find a contradiction with the assumption (that $f$ is even) doesn't mean that there isn't one. In other words, you did **NOT** prove that $f$ can be an even function. Hint for a correct proof: if some function $f(x)$ is a solution, what about $f(x)+C$?

b) You started well. Then apply Rolle's Theorem to $f'(x)$.

c) It follows from b) by applying Rolle's Theorem to $f(x)$.